# When menu visibility is turned off I can't see another pages content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a master page with the following code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
    <div id="header_container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerBar">
                <a href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") %>">
                    <img src="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/logo.png") %>" id="logo" /></a> <span id="header_text">
                        Scrum Reports</span>
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" CssClass="login_status" LogoutAction="Redirect"
                    LogoutPageUrl="~/default.aspx" />
                <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" CssClass="login_user" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuBar">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2"
            Orientation="Horizontal" >
        </asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1"  SiteMapProvider="admin" runat="server" />
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource2"  SiteMapProvider="user" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <!-- END: Sticky Header -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Main" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Page Content -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Sticky Footer -->
    <div id="footer_container">
        <div id="footer">
            Developed by Application Solutions
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Sticky Footer -->
    </form>
</body>
```

Now I am using the following C# (as part of the master pages `Page_Load` method)to show or hide the sites menu depending on whether a user is logged in:

```
Menu1.Visible = Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

For some reason, this line of code is preventing content from being seen on another page when the user isn't logged in.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/master/template.master" CodeFile="recoverpassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="password_recoverpassword" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" Visible="true" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="Server">
    <div>
    Cant see this content when not logged in.
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Why is this happening? What can I do about it?

Comment: What is in the code-behind for `recoverpassword.aspx.cs`?

Comment: The file is empty. I haven't added any code to it.

Comment: Perhaps you have a code somewhere (typo) that is like this: "Main.Visible = Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;"

Comment: I have checked, and in fact if I put Main.Visible = true; directly after the Menu1.Visible = Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; I have the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above:

```
Menu1.DataBind();
```

was causing the issue. When I removed it it it fixed it and everything else continued to work as normal.

Comment: Oh you mean the part you didn't show? Makes it hard to diagnose with missing info. LOL Glad you figured it out!